# Same Width for views in swiftUI

Tags: ios, iphone, swiftui, layout, vstack

I have a List and a button in VStack.

The button width needs to be the same as the ListView Width.

How can I make it the same in SwiftUI?
I am just a beginner in swiftUI, so I don't know any modifiers

[image] or something.

Comment: add frame(width:.infinity) to button

Comment: @JaiDeves, I already tried that but not working

Comment: @JaiDeves thank you for your answer, I got it
It should be `.frame(maxWidth:.infinity)`
Thank a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can force a `View` to use all the width available by setting `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)` (so `maxWidth` and not `width`, ref. comments). This modifier needs to come before you set the background, if you want the background to have the full width too.

Like this:

```swift
VStack {
    List(1...15, id: \.self) { num in
        Text("\(num)")
    }
    .listStyle(.plain)
    .shadow(radius: 10)

    Button("Confirm") {}
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity) // <- ADDED
        .padding()
        .background(.black)
}
.padding()
```

[image: Button]

If you're experimenting with modifiers then you might like to try it this way too:

```swift
Button {} label: {
    Text("Confirm")
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
}
.buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
.foregroundColor(.white)
.tint(.black)
```

BTW, another time, please paste the actual code into your question. This will make it easier for everyone wanting to help you to reproduce the problem. Thx.